# Creating SNS platform application with AWS Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create SNS platform application with Cloudformation template?

There is support for `aws-cli`, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/create-platform-application.html. But there is no information about doing the same with Cloudformation, is it supported at all (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html)?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Seems like the feature is not officially documented and I didn't find any examples at online. I ended up doing this as manual step through aws-cli.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I will have to do something similar. Its a shame.

Answer (score 13):

**NO**. It is **not** possible to create an SNS Platform Application using CloudFormation in AWS.

I am facing the same problem. In [AWS Could Formation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html) there are only `AWS::SNS::Subscription`, `AWS::SNS::Topic` and `AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy` today. None of them allows to define a Platform Application.

Unless it is possible to declare it under another `AWS::` service, it is not possible today. Hope to have this feature soon available.

**Kind of solution**:

• since creating/updating the Application Endpoint is a rare "event", once a year, I will manually :( create them.

• `awscli` and `aws-sdk` seem to support the creation of platform application, but it will add extra dependency or development

Answer (score 2):

It can be worth adding some extra work to get the benefits of automation and reproducibility.

I use `AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource` with a Lambda Function to do the work.

Add this to your CloudFormation definition.

```json
"MyPlatformApplication": {
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource",
    DependsOn: [ "PlatformApplicationProvisionLambdaFunction" ],
    Properties: {
        ServiceToken: { "Fn::GetAtt", "PlatformApplicationProvisionLambdaFunction.Arn" },
        Name: "MyPlatformApplication",
        Platform: "GCM",
        PlatformCredential: "<Your FCM ServerKey>",
    },
},
```

And define the Lambda Function `PlatformApplicationProvisionLambdaFunction` using your preferred strategy. For me, I use Serverless Framework so I can put the above custom resource together with the Lambda Function in the same repository and deploy all of them in one go.

Here is the Lambda code in Typescript

```js
import {
    CreatePlatformApplicationCommand,
    DeletePlatformApplicationCommand,
    SetPlatformApplicationAttributesCommand,
    SNSClient,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-sns';
import {
    CloudFormationCustomResourceCreateEvent,
    CloudFormationCustomResourceDeleteEvent,
    CloudFormationCustomResourceEvent,
    CloudFormationCustomResourceUpdateEvent,
    Context,
} from 'aws-lambda';
import response from 'cfn-response';
import middy from '@middy/core';
import middyJsonBodyParser from '@middy/http-json-body-parser';

const snsClient = new SNSClient({});

const parseInput = (event: CloudFormationCustomResourceEvent) => {
    const input = {
        Name: event.ResourceProperties.Name,
        Platform: event.ResourceProperties.Platform,
        PlatformCredential: event.ResourceProperties.PlatformCredential,
    };
    if (input.Name === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Missing parameter: Name');
    }
    if (input.Platform === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Missing parameter: Platform');
    }
    if (input.PlatformCredential === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Missing parameter: PlatformCredential');
    }
    return input;
};

const processCreate = async (event: CloudFormationCustomResourceCreateEvent, context: Context) => {
    const input = parseInput(event);
    const result = await snsClient.send(
        new CreatePlatformApplicationCommand({
            Name: input.Name,
            Platform: input.Platform,
            Attributes: {
                PlatformCredential: input.PlatformCredential,
            },
        }),
    );

    response.send(event, context, 'SUCCESS', {
        Arn: result.PlatformApplicationArn,
    });
};

const processUpdate = async (event: CloudFormationCustomResourceUpdateEvent, context: Context) => {
    const input = parseInput(event);
    const arn = `arn:aws:sns:${process.env.REGION}:${process.env.ACCOUNT_ID}:app/${input.Platform}/${input.Name}`;
    await snsClient.send(
        new SetPlatformApplicationAttributesCommand({
            PlatformApplicationArn: arn,
            Attributes: {
                PlatformCredential: input.PlatformCredential,
            },
        }),
    );
    response.send(event, context, 'SUCCESS', {
        Arn: arn,
    });
};

const processDelete = async (event: CloudFormationCustomResourceDeleteEvent, context: Context) => {
    const input = parseInput(event);
    const arn = `arn:aws:sns:${process.env.REGION}:${process.env.ACCOUNT_ID}:app/${input.Platform}/${input.Name}`;
    await snsClient.send(
        new DeletePlatformApplicationCommand({
            PlatformApplicationArn: arn,
        }),
    );
    response.send(event, context, 'SUCCESS', {
        Arn: arn,
    });
};

const handler = async (event: CloudFormationCustomResourceEvent, context: Context) => {

    try {
        if (event.RequestType === 'Create') {
            await processCreate(event, context);
        } else if (event.RequestType === 'Update') {
            await processUpdate(event, context);
        } else {
            await processDelete(event, context);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            response.send(event, context, 'FAILED', { message: err.message });
        } else {
            response.send(event, context, 'FAILED', err);
        }
    }
};

export const main = middy(handler).use(middyJsonBodyParser());
```